# How to make jquery multiple image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

It's a single image upload preview function in jquery. I want to change in the multiple functions like each box separately to upload photos which you can see in the html script below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script>

function imagepreview(input){
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        var filerd = new FileReader();
        filerd.onload=function(e){
            $('#imgpreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        filerd.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

</script>
<style>
body{
font-family:arial;
}
.wrap{
border:0px solid;
width:40%;
margin:10px auto;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}
#idupload{
    display:none;
}
.input-label{
    background-color:#009688;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><img id="imgpreview" src="" width="100" height="100"></th>
    <th><img id="imgpreview" src="" width="100" height="100"></th> 
    <th><img id="imgpreview" src="" width="100" height="100"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="idupload" class="input-label"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>upload</label><input type="file" id="idupload" onchange="imagepreview(this);" /></td>
    <td><label for="idupload" class="input-label"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>upload</label><input type="file" id="idupload" onchange="imagepreview(this);" /></td>
    <td><label for="idupload" class="input-label"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>upload</label><input type="file" id="idupload" onchange="imagepreview(this);" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have duplicate ID's, and the function `imagepreview()` is always updating the same ID with the image upload. To fix this, designate a unique ID to each image preview, and also place the same corresponding designation in the file upload boxes, so that a unique file upload box will update a unique image preview.

Here's a demo. I gave both the previews and the uploads a unique ID, then in `imagepreview()` I parse the ID of the upload box ID and add that to the ID of the image preview that is updated on the page. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apOyZB

Comment: can i add you on fb?

Comment: i want implement delete image event on same function?